# How to prove transitivity and antisymmetry of such Partial Order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I'm having problem with proving that a particular relation is Partial Order. Here is the task:

$ k, n \in \mathbb{N}_{+} $, $k\preceq n$ iff
$$ \exists j \in \mathbb{N} (2j + 1) k | n $$

Prove that $\preceq$ is partial order.

That's what I did:

**1) Reflexive**

$ a \preceq a $

$ \exists j \in \mathbb{N} (2j + 1) a | a $

And that j is simply 0. So reflexivity is proved.

**2) Antisymmetric**

$ a \preceq b \wedge b \preceq a \Rightarrow a = b $

$ (2j_{1} + 1) a | b \wedge (2j_{2} + 1)b | a $

I guess that's only possible when a = b. But is that a correct proof for that part?

**3) Transitivity**

I define new variables $ p, q, f \in \mathbb{N} $. I will use them for my equations to show divisibility.

$ (2j_{1}+1)ap=b \wedge (2j_{2}+1)bq=c \Rightarrow (2j_{3}+1)af=c $

Now after some operations I can see that:

$ (2j_{3}+1)f= (2j_{2}+1)(2j_{1}+1)pq $

But... I think it leads to nowhere, because I didn't show that $ j_{3} $ belongs to N. It doesn't matter how hard I try, I always end up with something that doesn't work. I thought about multiplying odd numbers, divisibility etc. but unfortunately it didn't help. Could you please help me with that proof? I guess there is an easier way to do it. I will be very grateful.

Comment: $\mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, \dots\} $?

Comment: @openspace If that's the question, then yes, they were defined for us like that (with zero). And if that's the hint then I'm sorry, I didn't get how could it help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2)** $(2j_{1} + 1) a | b \wedge (2j_{2} + 1)b | a$. From the definition of $|$ we have that $b =  m(2j_{1} + 1) a$. Substitute $b$ in the second equation and you have: $(2j_{2} + 1)m(2j_{1} + 1) a | a$. This tells us that a multiple of $a$ divides $a$, which can only happen if the multiple is itself $a$. So $(2j_{2} + 1)m(2j_{1} + 1)$ is equal to $1$ and since both numbers in the product are natural they are both equal to $1$. So we end up with $ a | b \wedge b | a$ which implies $a = b$.

**3)** $(2j_{1}+1)ap=b \wedge (2j_{2}+1)bq=c \Rightarrow (2j_{3}+1)af=c$. Simply substitute $b$ and you get $c = (2j_{2}+1)(2j_{1}+1)apq$. Now, set $f = pq$ and $(2j_{3}+1) = (2j_{2}+1)(2j_{1}+1)$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that I can just set f = pq, but now it makes sense. I will remember about that.

Comment: Think how you got $f$ in the first place. You got it from the definition of "divides", which says "there is some integer number such as...". $pq$ is obviously a natural, therefore integer, number so I just named it $f$ to match your statement.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbb{N} = \{0 ,1 , \dots \}$ then

1. $(2j_1+1) a | b \Rightarrow (2j_1+1) a \le b$ the same for $(2j_2+1)b | a \Rightarrow (2j_2+1)b \le a$, hence they are equal.
2. $a \preceq b \iff b = (2j_1+1)a q$ , $b \preceq c \iff c = (2j_2+1)b r$ hence we have that $c = (2j_2+1)(2j_1+1)a \cdot q \cdot r$. So $a \preceq c$

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense for me.